# Are there any hidden cost for using gtalk's voice call feature?

Tags: privacy, google-talk

I ve been talking to my friend who is US through gtalk's voice call feature for a month.. I really wanted to know are there any hidden cost for using gtalk's voice call feature?

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Questions about Web Apps are considered off topic on Super User. Questions within this scope are better fit on our Q&A website http://webapps.stackexchange.com which is currently in open beta. Your contribution will help it stay alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not definitive just based on my experience, but I have been using Google talk, Gmail voice and video chat, and the Google voice service daily for a couple of years. The only associated costs I have seen are.

1. If I send an SMS from any of the 
   services, the message is charged
   against the users monthly allotment
   (you would have to know how typically texting
   works in the US.
2. If I use Google voice to call an international land
   line, I am charged a nominal fee (in
   my case $.02 USD / min to China.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.

Comment: A) It wasn't marked off topic when I answered and I don't have the power to do so.  
2) SU is a very broad generally accepting community for general computer questions, I've seen much worse than this.  
iii) He had a question, I had experience, people help people when the opportunity arises even if it costs them rep.

Comment: it wasn't "marked" as such, but since you are a regular user, you know the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq). I understand that you knew the answer and wanted to help. Unfortunately, by answering an off-topic question, you go against the very fact that this is off-topic, since the person gets an answer anyway; so what for forbidding them in the first place? We try to keep a defined focus for SU, this is why we are strict on what is on or off-topic. Answering an off-topic question helps one user, but it doesn't help the site.

Comment: Google Talk is computer software. It happens to connect to Google. In my defense I saw it the same as Skype, Pidgin, or AIM.  
Beyond that I stand properly chastised and warned off and expecting further redress for starting a discussion which of course SU is also not intended for.

Answer (score 0):

there aren't hidden costs, but the 'free' price tag will not sustain much.
and remember always, even if you do get the calls for free, no one guarentees your calls are not called and later on initialised for whatever data they want to dig after.

Google has powerful algorythems and methods to build profiles for people and the day is not long before they will rely on voice over IP as well.
you can read in their pricing page (link: https://www.google.com/voice/rates )

googles privacy policy for google voice: http://www.google.com/googlevoice/privacy-policy.html

good luck.
and remember, big brother is always watching.